What would be the right approach to numerically integrate in MATLAB an improper integral with Bessel function?
I have an improper integral which contains Bessel functions, Cosine term as well as a rapidly decreasing exponential term. This is the integral:
$$\frac{1}{2\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{4\alpha}}\cos(\xi t)[J_0(\xi\eta)+J_0(\xi\zeta)] \xi d\xi$$
I found out that the exponential term is decaying rapidly. I mean it touches 0 at $\xi =2$ and doesn't get up. I tested this for values of $\xi$ up to 50,000 in MATLAB just to understand what's going on. Due to this term, the entire integrand also drops to zero really fast. I tried integrating the integral in MATLAB using the "integral" option in the R2022a version but the solution never converged. I have referred to this post but how else can I approach this issue? Is there a MATLAB-specific approach to this problem?

I solved this by observing the behaviour of the rapidly decreasing exponential function. It dropped to zero at about $\xi = 40$. So instead of integrating it from 0 to $\infty$, I integrate it from 0 to $\xi=40$ and that gave solutions which are matching with the reference.
